# Bootstrap $uibModal focus to element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, jqlite

I've created an AngularJs directive, which sets focus to a html element.
But it doesn't work on $uibModal elements:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo')
    .directive('focus', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.focus, function(value) {
                    if(value === true) {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            element[0].focus();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BrnFt1kYZN7VsIFRCt3S?p=preview

How can I set focus to an element inside a $uibModal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the solution:
When I add the autofocus attribute to an input element, the $uibModal sets the focus to it.

```
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus/>
        </p>
    </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/yMNLLnSZL86ZYLsnuDV9?p=preview

Comment: works great ! especially since in most cases you don't have access to the link function of this.